# FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture x86_64 building for Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, mac-catalyst

I run my project for mac with catalyst, I got a below error. for Firebase

[Please see below link for pod file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ge3dBBwbLeqXJGg1ZgrEpZDULQ78FZoD/view)

```
/Users/ios/Desktop/xxxxxx/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector(FIRConnectorUtils_d79571aba36a7d46e5c6ca87a6fec1c1.o), building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for iOS Simulator, file '/Users/ios/Desktop/xxxxxx/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework/FIRAnalyticsConnector' for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `pod Firebase/Analytics` from the Podfile.

Firebase Analytics does not currently support Catalyst. Full details about Firebase support for Catalyst at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#development-for-catalyst.

Add a thumbs-up to https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4563 to indicate interest in Analytics support.

In the meantime, a workaround to conditionally add Analytics only for iOS, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58768815/556617

Comment: thanks for reply, Ya it is true. Waiting for mac catalyst support.
Happy New Year

Comment: thanks for reply, Yes, it is true. Waiting for mac catalyst support. Click on Add thumbs-up to also done  Happy New Year.

Comment: is there a way to conditionally have Firebase/Analytics for iOS and not for macOS ?

Comment: @AnkurPatel Any new update regrading Analytics support for Mac catalyst?

Comment: @YogendraPatel There is a beta available. Details in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4563

Comment: @AnkurPatel can you please provide beta setup steps?

Answer (score 0):

While Cocoapods is not yet supported, I've been able to install and run Firebase Analytics & Crashlytics in a Mac Catalyst app using `Swift Package Manager` ([documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods?authuser=1))

1. In Xcode, install the Firebase libraries by navigating to File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency…
2. In the prompt that appears, select the Firebase GitHub repository:
   https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git
3. Select the desired Frameworks (Analytics, Crashlytics...)

4. Make sure to add the same frameworks in `Build Phases / Link Binary with Libraries` of your target.