# How to fix various CocoaPods not supporting Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, mac-catalyst, google-ads-api

I have an iPad app using Google Mobile Ads SDK through CocoaPods and would like to port it to Mac Catalyst. However, the underlying Pods like Google App Measurement does not support Mac Catalyst. When I try to port it, it shows a compile time error saying "...building for Mac Catalyst, but compiling for iOS Simulator" (roughly paraphrasing here).

I tried [this solution on Medium](https://medium.com/better-programming/macos-catalyst-debugging-problems-using-catalyst-and-cocoapods-579679150fa9) (scroll down to "Automate the Process" section). Namely I modified the Podfile to exclude the incompatible libraries from compiling on Mac Catalyst. However when I do that, it removes the previous errors but is giving me two new errors:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADMobileAds
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest
```

I don't know how to remove these errors and make it compile on Mac Catalyst. Do you know how to solve them?

Comment: The Google Mobile Ads SDK does not currently support Catalyst.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien How to exclude the SDK from compiling on Catalyst?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635911/exclude-pod-when-porting-to-mac-with-catalyst/58768815#58768815

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude pod when porting to mac with catalyst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635911/exclude-pod-when-porting-to-mac-with-catalyst)