# Trying to add a SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST = NO to a target in Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Tags: cocoapods

Trying to modify my Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST = NO;

Couldn't figure out how to do it in the post_install. Even doing a string substitution fails because the file is rewritten after post_install.

How would I accomplish this?

I'm just calling pod install and doing the string substitution from python because I coulnd't figure it out.

Want each instance of the target to end up like this...

```
        A6D12E137457B5D01713900826D040DF /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            baseConfigurationReference = B153262FC922C0095F31C275EF9D0726 /* MWPhotoBrowser.debug.xcconfig */;
            buildSettings = {
                CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = "$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)/MWPhotoBrowser";
                IBSC_MODULE = MWPhotoBrowser;
                INFOPLIST_FILE = "Target Support Files/MWPhotoBrowser/ResourceBundle-MWPhotoBrowser-MWPhotoBrowser-Info.plist";
                IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 6.0;
                PRODUCT_NAME = MWPhotoBrowser;
                SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST = NO; /*ADDED FROM COCOAPODS*/
                SDKROOT = iphoneos;
                SKIP_INSTALL = YES;
                TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2";
                WRAPPER_EXTENSION = bundle;
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58768815/556617

Comment: Thanks @PaulBeusterien That works for the xcconfig for a pod but I was trying to update the Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj. I couldn't figure out how  to override the SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST using that scheme.